# How to select a object in jq that matches on a greater or less than for multiple values in a attribute

Tags: json, jq

Using jq, I am searching through a large json file that has objects that contain multiple year values in a attribute. I want to be able to narrow my search and only retrieve objects that are greater or less(older or younger) than YEAR(example 2015). This is tricky because the attributes can have multiple year values, some greater and less than the year I am searching for.

Here is a example of the code I am searching through. It's all basically this.

```
cat stackover.json

{
    "tokens": [
{
 "Name": "stack overflow",
  "year": [
    "1997",
    "1998",
    "1997"
  ]
},
{
  "Name": "Return pizza",
  "year": [
    "1998",
    "2015",
    "2014",
    "1998"
  ]
}
]
}
```

I know how to search for a contains one of the values... but can figure out how to search all the values and determine if all of them are less than 2000.

If I search for less than '<', then I get no out put back. If I search for greater than '>', then I get back both object multiple times

```
cat stackover.json | jq '.tokens[] | select(.year[] > 2000)'
{
  "Name": "stack overflow",
  "year": [
    "1997",
    "1998",
    "1997"
  ]
}
{
  "Name": "stack overflow",
  "year": [
    "1997",
    "1998",
    "1997"
  ]
}
{
  "Name": "stack overflow",
  "year": [
    "1997",
    "1998",
    "1997"
  ]
}
{
  "Name": "Return pizza",
  "year": [
    "1998",
    "2015",
    "2014",
    "1998"
  ]
}
{
  "Name": "Return pizza",
  "year": [
    "1998",
    "2015",
    "2014",
    "1998"
  ]
}
{
  "Name": "Return pizza",
  "year": [
    "1998",
    "2015",
    "2014",
    "1998"
  ]
}
{
  "Name": "Return pizza",
  "year": [
    "1998",
    "2015",
    "2014",
    "1998"
  ]
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish.

If I search for anything less than 2000, I want a query that will only return "stack overflow" since it does not have a 20XX value in the available values.

```
cat stackover.json | code searching for only objects(stack overflow) where all values are less than 2000. 

{
  "Name": "stack overflow",
  "year": [
    "1997",
    "1998",
    "1997"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines.  Also please note that the provided snippet of output is incomplete. A small sample of FFF.json would probably also be helpful.

Comment: Is this explanation any better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In brief, `all/2` is your friend.

Assuming we have defined $mx (a string) as the cutoff year, a suitable filter would be:

```
.tokens[] | select( all(.year[]; . < $mx) )
```

The command-line option '--arg mx N' interprets N as a string, so a suitable invocation would be like so:

```
jq --arg mx 2000 -f filter.jq stackover.json
```

(Notice that we can avoid converting the dates to numbers by letting $mx be a string.)

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.  

cat stackover.json | jq --arg mx 2000 '.tokens[] | select( all(.year[]; . < $mx) )'
{
  "Name": "stack overflow",
  "year": [
    "1997",
    "1998",
    "1997"
  ]
}